# Facebook Graph API not returning all events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API, via the PHP SDK, to fetch a list of events attached to a Facebook page. The page has 15 events, all public; if I query them from the links in the developer documentation (i.e. with the sample access key it gives you there) I can see all fifteen of them.

That sample URL, the one that works fine, is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[the name of the page]/events?access_token=[the access token]
```

If, though, I do the same request via the PHP SDK — that is, from calling:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

$result = $facebook->api('[the name of the page]/events');
```

…then it returns only nine events, not the full fifteen. I've tried seemingly every combination of parameters: I've tried `limit`ing it to 10, 15, 100, 500; I've tried setting various `offset`s; I've set either or both `since` and `until`. I've tried to think of all the gotchas: the events are definitely public, and show up if I visit the page's "Events" tab while logged out of Facebook. Whatever I do, I just get those same nine events, mocking me with their incompleteness.

Does anyone have any ideas? The events that aren't showing are the most recently added ones, if that makes any difference, though they were added to Facebook days — rather than hours or minutes — ago. I can't think why that would make a difference, though, and I've had events show up within minutes of being added before.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is directly related to your question, but when you retrieve some user's events, you only get those that have been responded by the user (will attend, maybe, or not).

Comment: @manuelpedrera No dice, I'm afraid; I've tried RSVP'ing to the events as both the page (using the new "Use Facebook as page" feature) and as a page admin, and it doesn't work — and I guess that wouldn't explain why it appears in the request using the example page's access token. I'm beginning to think it's something to do with my access token, since that's the only thing that's changing between those two requests, but surely if my token was invalid I would receive no data and an OAuth exception — not incomplete data. Argh!

Comment: Facing same issue while fetching public events.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this links helps, got the same problem reported to bugtracker of facebook...

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16617

You have to set the flag "Show guestlist", if this is not
checked the event is not available via graph api.

Comment: Link is broken now. Is this information up to date? And what if I want to get event that I'm not the owner of? I am invited to it and can see it in normal way.

Comment: Your link is not working, pls don't put URL in answers. if URL is closed than your answer is not available for others.